# How do you merge two Pandas dataframes with different column index levels?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to concatenate two dataframes with same indices but different column-levels. One dataframe has a hierarchical index, the other on doesnt.

```
print df1

              A_1               A_2               A_3                .....
              Value_V  Value_y  Value_V  Value_y  Value_V  Value_y

instance200   50       0        6500     1        50       0
instance201   100      0        6400     1        50       0
```

the other one:

```
print df2

              PV         Estimate

instance200   2002313    1231233
instance201   2134124    1124724
```

result should look like this:

```
             PV        Estimate   A_1               A_2               A_3                .....
                                  Value_V  Value_y  Value_V  Value_y  Value_V  Value_y

instance200  2002313   1231233    50       0        6500     1        50       0
instance201  2134124   1124724    100      0        6400     1        50       0
```

but a merge or concatenate on the frames will give me a df with a one-dimensional column index like that:

```
             PV        Estimate   (A_1,Value_V) (A_1,Value_y) (A_2,Value_V) (A_2,Value_y)  .....


instance200  2002313   1231233    50             0             6500         1
instance201  2134124   1124724    100            0             6400         1
```

How can i keep the hierarchical index from df1?

Answer (score 14):

Perhaps use good ole assignment:

```
df3 = df1.copy()
df3[df2.columns] = df2
```

yields

```
                A_1             A_2             A_3               PV Estimate
            Value_V Value_y Value_V Value_y Value_V Value_y                  
instance200      50       0    6500       1      50       0  2002313  1231233
instance201     100       0    6400       1      50       0  2134124  1124724
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do this by making df2 have the same number of levels as df1:

```
In [11]: df1
Out[11]:
                A_1             A_2             A_3
            Value_V Value_y Value_V Value_y Value_V Value_y
instance200      50       0    6500       1      50       0
instance201     100       0    6400       1      50       0

In [12]: df2
Out[12]:
                  PV  Estimate
instance200  2002313   1231233
instance201  2134124   1124724

In [13]: df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df2.columns, [None] * len(df2.columns)])

In [14]: df2
Out[14]:
                  PV Estimate
                 NaN      NaN
instance200  2002313  1231233
instance201  2134124  1124724
```

Now you are able to do the concat without mangling the column names:

```
In [15]: pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
Out[15]:
                A_1             A_2             A_3               PV Estimate
            Value_V Value_y Value_V Value_y Value_V Value_y      NaN      NaN
instance200      50       0    6500       1      50       0  2002313  1231233
instance201     100       0    6400       1      50       0  2134124  1124724
```

Note: to have the df2 columns first use `pd.concat([df2, df1], axis=1)`.

---

*That said, I'm not sure I can think of a use case for this, keeping them as separate DataFrames might be actually be an easier solution...!*

Answer (score 1):

I made a wrapper for the `pandas.concat` function, which accepts dataframes with an unequal number of levels.

The empty levels are added from below. The advantage is that it is allows for accessing the series with `df_cols.c` (in `df_cols` below), and also, when printing, makes it clear that `'c'` isn't a sublevel of `('CC', 'one')`.

```py
def concat(dfs, axis=0, *args, **kwargs):   
    """
    Wrapper for `pandas.concat'; concatenate pandas objects even if they have 
    unequal number of levels on concatenation axis.
    
    Levels containing empty strings are added from below (when concatenating along
    columns) or right (when concateniting along rows) to match the maximum number 
    found in the dataframes.
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    dfs : Iterable
        Dataframes that must be concatenated.
    axis : int, optional
        Axis along which concatenation must take place. The default is 0.

    Returns
    -------
    pd.DataFrame
        Concatenated Dataframe.
    
    Notes
    -----
    Any arguments and kwarguments are passed onto the `pandas.concat` function.
    
    See also
    --------
    pandas.concat
    """
    def index(df):
        return df.columns if axis==1 else df.index
    
    def add_levels(df):
        need = want - index(df).nlevels
        if need > 0:
            df = pd.concat([df], keys=[('',)*need], axis=axis) # prepend empty levels
            for i in range(want-need): # move empty levels to bottom
                df = df.swaplevel(i, i+need, axis=axis) 
        return df
    
    want = np.max([index(df).nlevels for df in dfs])    
    dfs = [add_levels(df) for df in dfs]
    return pd.concat(dfs, axis=axis, *args, **kwargs)
```

Hope that's of help to someone.

Test:

```
df1

   AA      BB      CC    
  one     one     one    
    a   b   a   b   a   b
0  91  63   2  59  26  93
1  34   4  73  55  16  66
2   2   6   9  15  51  95

df2

    c   d   e
0  68  49  69
1  35  53  71
2  68  75  54


df3

       c   d   e
i  x  27  83  53
   y  54  51   9
   z  41   1  24
ii x  44  76  54
   y  76  85  21
   z  83  82   6


df_cols = concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

df_cols

   AA      BB      CC       c   d   e
  one     one     one                
    a   b   a   b   a   b            
0  91  63   2  59  26  93  68  49  69
1  34   4  73  55  16  66  35  53  71
2   2   6   9  15  51  95  68  75  54


df_rows = concat([df2, df3])

df_rows

       c   d   e
0     68  49  69
1     35  53  71
2     68  75  54
i  x  27  83  53
   y  54  51   9
   z  41   1  24
ii x  44  76  54
   y  76  85  21
   z  83  82   6
```

Answer (score 0):

Update (Jan, 20201)
I built a function for this purpose as follows:

```
def concat( df1, df2 ):

  """
  Function concatenates two dataframes df1 snd df2 even if the two datafames
  have different number of hierarchical columns levels.

  In the case of one dataframe having more hierarchical columns levels than the
  other, blank string will be added to the upper hierarchical columns levels
  """

  nLevels1 = df1.columns.nlevels
  nLevels2 = df2.columns.nlevels
  diff     = nLevels2 - nLevels1

  mLevels  = max(nLevels1, nLevels2)

  if nLevels1 == nLevels2:
    # if the same simply concat as normal
    return pd.concat( [df1, df2 ], axis = 1 )

  elif nLevels1 < nLevels2:
    # if there is a difference expand smaller dataframe with black strings, then concat

    df_temp = df1.copy()
    new_cols  = [[""] * len( df1.columns )] * np.abs(diff)

    new_cols = join_lists( df1.columns, new_cols)
    df_temp.columns = new_cols

    concatonated = pd.concat( [df_temp, df2 ], axis = 1 )
    return concatonated

  elif nLevels1 > nLevels2:
    # same as above but for the other way around

    df_temp = df2.copy()


    new_cols = [[""] * len( df2.columns )] * np.abs(diff)
    new_cols = join_lists( df2.columns, new_cols)

    new_cols.append( df2.columns.to_list() )

    df_temp.columns = new_cols

    concatonated = pd.concat( [df1, df_temp ], axis = 1)

    return concatonated
```

Now if we provide the dataframes

```
gender  f  m
            
n       2  1
y       2  2
```

and

```
gender        f                         m             
age         old        young          old        young
location london paris london paris london paris london
                                                      
n             1     0      1     0      0     1      0
y             0     1      0     1      1     0      1
```

we get

```
             f                         m                   
            old        young          old        young      
         london paris london paris london paris london  f  m
                                                            
n             1     0      1     0      0     1      0  2  1
y             0     1      0     1      1     0      1  2  2
```

Note, it might be nice to join the category gender in future such that they are on the same level, but this is largely for joining dataframes with entirely different columns.

Comment: I think you meant to change the column names of `df2` in that second-to-last line. Also, note that calling this function also changes `df1` or `df2`, which is bad practise.

Comment: Thanks, there were several issues with this code that I had to fix. I've replaced with the latest version of this which I believe works well, although your solution certainly looks a little more concise :)